# Kendo Popup Editing - 4 column template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this requirment in which all my grids (about 20) of them have pop up editing. Also the form fields have to be displayed on 4 column layout. (against the default single column)

Is there a configuration that I can do so the form fields appear in 4 columns instead of having to write about 20 different custom templates ?

So for example I have 2 grids as following
Grid1: Field1, Field2, Field3....Field9
Grid2: Field1, Field2, Field3....Field11

I need to display the popup edit form so that the form fields **are displayed** in 4 columns

**Grid1:**

Field1     Field2    Field3    Field4

Field5     Field6    Field7    Field8

Field9

**Grid2:**

Field1     Field2    Field3    Field4

Field5     Field6    Field7    Field8

Field9     Field10    Field11

So just for this display, I have to make a template (2 times) and it becomes cumbersome to maintain as the number of grids increase.

Comment: I think this link - [Custom PopUp Editor](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor.aspx) can help you.

Comment: There is not but definitely you don't have to write it 20 times. Can you provide more details about what would be in those 4 columns? Do you mean 4 fields, then the next 4 fields and so on? or is that your grids have 4 columns and that's what you want?

Comment: @OnaBai, Updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: @NEHAVERMA8, have been solved this require?